# Powershell printer script

Tags: powershell, printers

I will translate my question in english so that everyone can read it!

Am not really good in powershell i work on it for 3 days.

I need to create a powershell script  to show what is the default printer selected in the computer ( example :*PrinterA*) before the execute a line to select another printer as default printer ( *PrinterB*) .

After that i need to reset the old default printer  ( *PrinterA*).

I execute line:

`Get-WmiObject -query " SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer WHERE Default=$true"`

to show default printer but i dont know how to memorize it.

To select the (*printeB* ), I do:

```
RUNDLL32 PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry /y /n "PrinteB"
```

Can you help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use

```
$OldDefaultPrinter = (Get-WmiObject win32_printer | Where-Object Default -eq $True).Name
```

To store the current default printer in a variable.

To restore with your method

```
RUNDLL32 PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry /y /n "$OldDefaultPrinter"
```

Answer (score 0):

you did not mention the specific version of Powershell that you are using. [*grin*] presuming you are running ps5.1 on win10, you can use the print management cmdlets to do what you need. take a look at this ...

PrintManagement
— https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/printmanagement/?view=win10-ps

the `Get-Printer` cmdlet will get info about the available printers. the `Set-Printer` cmdlet will let you set the default printer.